# How do I connect to SFTP using jsch from Web application?

Tags: java, servlets, sftp, tomcat6, jsch

I am by no means an expert programmer.
My current situation is this.
I built a java project that uses jsch to connect to an SFTP server to send/retrieve files. rsa private key and passcode were required in the code to be added for identity. I also added known_hosts. Everything worked, I was able to connect to the SFTP server and download/upload files.

Next, I tried to put my code into a Maven project that uses Tomcat. So I created the jsp page with a few buttons then send it off using java servlets to execute my code on the server-side. This is where I've run into a brick wall. At first, I was receiving nullpointerexceptions and found out it was due to permission settings. I had to change a few directories/files to chmod 777 (really bad for security I know), but even after that I've run into an Auth Fail error. I've been scouring through the internet to try and find a solution, but failed to do so. Please help, it would be greatly appreciated.

I'm not sure if it matters or not, but clients are using Windows to connect to the web application, whereas the server is running UbuntU 14.04.

Thanks!

### Edit: Hopefully this is sufficient

### In Web.XML, I've included

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>sftpConn</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>package.sftpClass</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>sftpConn</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/process</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

---

### In JSP Page

```
<%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
<jsp:useBean id="sftpConnection"
    class="package.sftpClass"
    scope="request" />

<html>
<head>
<title>sftp transfer</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/process" method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="Test" value="Test" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Finally in sftpClass.java (all my variables are set to private and initialized from config file using Scanner)

```
public void connect () {

    String workingDir = "/transfer";

    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    ChannelSftp channelSftp = null;
    try {
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        jsch.addIdentity(privateKey, privateKeyPassword);
        jsch.setKnownHosts(knownHosts);
        session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
        session.setPassword(pass);
        session.connect();
        channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
        channel.connect();
        channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;
        channelSftp.cd(workDir);
        File f = new File(filePath);
        channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(f), f.getName());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printstacktrace();        
    } finally {
        channelSftp.exit();
        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();
    }
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    sftpClass s = new sftpClass();

    if (request.getParameter("Test") != null) {
        try {
            s.connect();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printstacktrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you once again.

Hi, this is what I get from my stacktrace log in Catalina.out

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Auth fail
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:395)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:148)
    at package.sftpClass.connect(sftpClass.java:1224)
    at package.sftpClass.create(sftpClass.java:820)
    at package.sftpClass.doPost(sftpClass.java:1337)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:643)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at oscar.oscarSecurity.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at net.sf.cookierevolver.servlet.CRFilterImpl.doFilter(CRFilterImpl.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.oscarehr.util.LoggedInUserFilter.doFilter(LoggedInUserFilter.java:60)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.oscarehr.util.DbConnectionFilter.doFilter(DbConnectionFilter.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.oscarehr.util.ResponseDefaultsFilter.doFilter(ResponseDefaultsFilter.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.oscarehr.util.ProblemCheckFilter.doFilter(ProblemCheckFilter.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide the code that doesn't work for you and we will try to help. Thanks!

Comment: Enable [JSch logging](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Logger.java.html) and show us a log both from working (desktop?) environment and failing web environment.

Comment: I have included my logging, I have managed to connect SFTP without using a private key. It is only when I perform the jsch.addIdentity(privatekey,pass) and try to do a session.connect() that fails. I've even tried to set full permission and chmod 777 to the directories that are used by my code. Any idea? Thanks.

Comment: That's a callstack, not log.

Comment: After further troubleshooting, I've set up an sftp server on the remote host which does public key authentication. On my client I have user1 and user2, I had to generate key pairs for both and appended both public keys to the authorized_keys file on the remote host to be able to connect. My question is, how do I do this for tomcat6 on my client computer? I am thinking either generate a key pair (private key + csr), or somehow get tomcat6 to use my credentials. If I figure this out, I feel that would be the solution to my problem.

Comment: I am a beginner at this, so any misinformation I am sorry about. Please help, thank you.